# Cannot log in to server after SSH port change

Tags: ssh

I was doing fine with default ssh port 22 on my remote server
then i read somewhere if i change the port to 2222 at least i can stop some automated login attempt to my ssh server
so i've decided to change the port on my server

**What I've Changed**

System: Ubuntu 8.04 32bits with sudo apt-get install ssh

```
vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

change port 22 to port 2222

```
/etc/init.d/sshd restart
```

After i changed and restarted sshd
It can't seem to work, now Im locked out of it
but im sure port is open;

**to test it i use telnet to port 2222**

```
telnet wwww.example.com 2222 i get reply
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.7p1 Debian-8ubuntu1.2
```

**nmap port scan it**
    nmap -p 2222 www.mywebsite.com

Starting Nmap 4.53 ( http://insecure.org ) 
Interesting ports on www.mywebsite.com (x.x.x.x):
PORT     STATE SERVICE

```
2222/tcp open  unknown
```

router: linksys 54GL
router firmware: Firmware: DD-WRT v24-sp1 vpn

i used port forwarding to map router port 2222 to my pc's port 2222

only 1 user..

**thanks to shuvalo**

> ssh -v -p 2222 www.example.com

```
joec@server:~$ ssh -v -p2222 www.example.com
OpenSSH_4.7p1 Debian-8ubuntu1.2, OpenSSL 0.9.8g 19 Oct 2007
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to www.example.com[100.100.100.100] port 2222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/joec/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/joec/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/joec/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.7p1 Debian-8ubuntu1.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.7p1 Debian-8ubuntu1.2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.7p1 Debian-8ubuntu1.2
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Connection closed by 100.100.100.100
```

I hope these helps

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of: [ssh connection stop at “debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent”
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419412/ssh-connection-stop-at-debug1-ssh2-msg-kexinit-sent)

Answer (score 1):

How are you sshing into the server? What command are you running / program are you using? Are you using Putty (Windows).

If you are using the ssh command line program, your ssh command should be

```
ssh -p 2222 www.mywebsite.com
```

unless you have edited `~/.ssh/config` on the client.

Comment: i've used putty, secureCRT, ubuntu linux terminal from couple different PCs.. connection all got dropped

Answer (score 1):

show output from `ssh -v -p2222 youdserver.com`